# AndroidX Jetifier unable/failed to transform 3rd-party transitive dependency that still use Support Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetifier

I've recently migrated my project to use **AndroidX**

My apps crashes, after I migrate to **AndroidX**, due to library still using **Support Library**. Here's a list of my 3rd-party dependencies/library, that failed to transform into **AndroidX**:

1. `com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.4.2`
2. `com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0`
3. `com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.4.0`
4. `jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0`
5. `com.github.chivorns:smartmaterialspinner:1.1.6`
6. `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.1`
7. `com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:7.0.1` (I still cannot upgrade it to 10.x.x, because major API changes)
8. `com.github.nikartm:image-support:1.0.5`

My Setups:

```
AS & AGP: 3.6.2
targetSdk: 29
minSdk: 16
Data & View Binding: Both enabled
Gradle DSL: Kotlin
Gradle: gradle-6.0.1-all
```

What I've done so far:

1. Using `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX` tools from **Android Studio**, but ended-up force close it, because takes a long time
2. `android.enableJetifier=true` & `android.useAndroidX=true`
3. Using the shell scripts to manually mapping [artifact, class and imports](https://gist.github.com/mochadwi/d233e4996f3e498f08f57d073e366c9b) from **Support Library** to **AndroidX**, [thanks @Danlew](https://blog.danlew.net/2018/11/14/the-reality-of-migrating-to-androidx/), also [@Danlew mentioned in ADS '19 talks here](https://youtu.be/Hyt7LR5mXLc?t=584)
4. Already checked my `:app:dependencies` that 3rd-party dependencies already migrated to use **AndroidX** artifacts, but only a few of them (failed for the above dependencies list)
5. Deleting `./root_project/.idea`, `./root_project/.gradle` & `~/.gradle/caches` (to fix compile-error/IDE error, references: [AndroidX migrate dependency / libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518935/androidx-migrate-dependency-libraries)
6. Understanding the jetifier: [What is Jetifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier) & [official android docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/jetifier)
7. Did a workaround to use **AndroidX** for annotation processor like: [Glide & Dagger](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3080#issuecomment-495430590)
8. Checking the `~/.gradle` directories for the `jetified-*` libs [image: screenshot of my <code>~/.gradle</code> contents] the `jetified` aar exist, unfortunately it's failed for `clevertap` & others libs listed above.

My conclusions, the `jetifier` works by rewriting the binary `.class` of our 3rd-party library if **Support Library** imports/class detected, and modify (jetified/mapping it) into **AndroidX** respectively.

But in my case, the **dependencies listed above** doesn't use correct **AndroidX** imports and resulting runtime crash, due to having a transitive dependent for **Support Library**.

Does jetifier currently doesn't support transitive dependency inside 3rd-party library as well? But, strangely it works for a few library (unlisted from above)

**[UPDATED 1]**

In the meantime (quickfix):

1. I did downloading all the transitive dependencies of the libraries exhaustively one-by-one
2. Using [`jetifier-standalone`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3080#issuecomment-495430590) commands instead for the libraries `aar`
3. Manually adding the libraries `aar` and its dependencies to `app/build.gradle.kts` as `flatDirs`

Is this really a workaround, is there anything better I can do?

**[UPDATED 2]**

I've using a maintained version of chuck as well. But found this same issue as well:

```
cannot generate view binders com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView not found
```

After checking my 3rd-party libs, I also ended-up manually adding the `aar` after I use `jetifier-standalone` for this library:

1. `com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.4.2`
2. `com.github.nikartm:image-support:1.0.5`

Many also recommends to use [`api` instead of `implementation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48811145/3763032) but for me, I don't want to bloated my project with transitive dependency

In [other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53503768/3763032) also recommends below:

1. either remove the library,
2. forked it to support androidx / waiting for the author to upgrade it
3. manually using `jetifier-standalone` for those specicif libs, and include as local aar (this is my best approach, right now)

Unless the `jetifier` able to state this into official documentation, for its limitation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/jetifier

Seems like there's the least we can do, and hope, many of the 3rd-party authors will upgrade to **AndroidX** soon.

Here's a bonus article for references:

1. You can use [can-i-drop-jetifier](https://github.com/plnice/can-i-drop-jetifier/) libs to [detects does your libs (transitively) needs jetifier enabled or not](https://proandroiddev.com/the-state-of-jetification-in-early-2019-plus-a-bonus-gradle-plugin-aac5854af910)
2. [The time is right to migrate to **AndroidX** with this baby-steps](https://medium.com/@markchristopherng/the-time-is-right-move-to-android-x-now-6de2c608135a)
3. [Better structure packaging with **AndroidX** and also a headache along the way](https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-series-1-androidx-a-headache-for-a-better-package-structure-62c3608596fd)

Comment: Have you tried using the [actually maintained fork of chuck](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker)?

Comment: thanks @ianhanniballake for pointing me to the maintained chuck, will update it. I've also update my question for details about the list of dependencies that failed. Do I've to rewrite my ownself that library to support androidx or manually using `jetifier-standalone`? Or is there any approach I can do?

Comment: I've updated it to use maintained chuck libs, but found this issue now: `cannot generate view binders com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView not found` does this means, jetifier failed to transform other library to AndroidX? @ianhanniballake I've also delete my .gradle & .idea seems doesn't works either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my current workaround was using this approach: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3080#issuecomment-495430590

Magical regex to turns a blacklist into a whiteliset

```
android.jetifier.blacklist=^(?!.*[\\\\/](com\\.github\\.bumptech\\.glide|com\\.clevertap\\.android|com\\.facebook\\.android|com\\.github\\.nikartm|com\\.github\\.PierfrancescoSoffritti|com\\.github\\.prolificinteractive)[\\\\/]).*$
```

If `NoClassDef` exceptions thrown, then I add the library package name into the `android.jetifier.blacklist` to whitelisted them.

In the above cases, I'm trying to whitelist:

1. glide
2. clevertap
3. nikartm
4. facebook-sdk
5. YoutubeAndroidPlayer (v7) still not using v10
6. prolificinteractive